# слой из JSON-файла

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Имеется GeoJSON-файл с координатами зданий и описанием. Как (и можно ли) создать слой из этих данных?

Comment: Какой слой вы хотите создать? Можно к примеру их добавить на карту через  Object Manager

Comment: Через Object Manager - это каждый раз перебирать массив и отрисовывать все заново? То же, что и geoQuery. Это тяжело. 60000 точек не отрисовываются. Про полигоны молчу.

Comment: Можно ли прикрутить shape-файл в виде слоя? Или можно ли как то положить мои полигоны на тайловый слой?

Comment: Класс Layer  - он только для работы с тайловыми слоями? А можно ли например создать точечный или полигональный слой?

Comment: Ну тогда можно попробовать через https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/hotspots/about-hotspots-docpage/ и пример есть https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/hotspot_layer

Comment: Похоже то, что нужно. А можно ли в качестве картиночного слоя использовать просто пустой прозрачный png-файл? Или можно ли вообще без него обойтись?

Comment: Прошу прощения. Не дочитал. " В некоторых случаях слой активных областей может использоваться и без картиночного (например, если нужно сделать интерактивным изображение какого-то дома на карте)"

Comment: При запуске примера через IDE не открывается baloon и не меняет свою форму курсор. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: В консоли наверно должна быть информация о том что есть проблемы с тайлами, например они не загружаются.

Comment: разобрался. hotspot не работает же на клиенте)))))) Поэтому так"var tileUrlTemplate = 'hotspot_data/%z/tile_x=%x&y=%y',"  не работало. Сделал так: "var tileUrlTemplate = 'http://localhost/hotspot_data/%z/tile_x=%x&y=%y',". Я там другой вопрос задал. Гляньте, если не трудно.